Type vs. Set Theory: Expressive Ability
In the modern mathematical arena, the two primary contenders for the ‘correct’ foundation of mathematics are set and type theory.
Set theory, very roughly, captures the intuition that we frequently want to ‘gather things up’ in mathematical practice to study them as a whole.
Type theory, very very roughly, captures the intuition that mathematical objects in practice seem to have fundamentally differing natures in different fields, and that we should keep track of those differing natures.

Which foundation has more expressive ability?

For the purposes of this question, by ‘expressive power’ I mean ‘ability to model mathematical phenomenon’ which I will (controversially) formalize via consistency strength, but I’m open to arguments using other metrics.
I’m aware, for example, that HoTT is equiconsistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}+{}$inaccessibles, but on the set theory side we have far more powerful axioms of infinity to play around with which easily establish the consistency of both theories. Are there comparable type theoretic axioms that blow the consistency strength of base HoTT to something like $\mathrm{ZFC}+0^\#$ or higher? Any arguments for either side are appreciated.

Perhaps the interpretability hierarchy is more natural than consistency strength. But actually, for both the consistency strength and interpretability hierarchies, I am unsure what it means exactly to compare a first-order theory such as ZFC or ZFC + large cardinals to a type theory, which is after all not a first-order theory. Do type theories have a consistency strength in the first-order sense of this term? Can we accommodate them into into the hierarchy of relative interpretability?

In a reasonably expressive type theory like HoTT (with universes), you can always add axioms of the form 'the Aczel interpretation of ZFC has large cardinal X.' I don't think this has really been explored very much in the type theory literature, but there's no problem with it in principle.

@JoelDavidHamkins There shouldn't be too much issue with talking about consistency strength of type theories and interpretability relative to first-order theories. I believe this is done a fair amount in the existing literature.

@JamesEHanson I'm glad to hear that. For a given type theory $T$ of the kinds usually considered, can one form an arithmetic expression $\text{Con}(T)$ of the consistency of the theory, and hope to prove things about it in PA? If so, then it would be clear how to incorporate it into the consistency strength hierarchy. What does it mean exactly to say that such a type theory is interpretable in a given first-order theory?

Possibly related: How true are theorems proved by Coq? The question itself is maybe not so directly related, but some of the answers and comments address the relationship between type theory and set theory.

@JoelDavidHamkins For an arbitrary (possibly weak) type theory, the definition of consistency would usually be something like 'there is a type $A$ such that for no term $t$, $\vdash t : A$.' (Although this is a little iffy, since it implies Isabelle/HOL's type theory is inconsistent, but it's still usable. Sometimes there is more than one way to interpret logic in a type theory and they don't necessarily result in the same notion of consistency.) Since the set of Gödel codes of terms and types satisfying $\vdash t : A$ is c.e., this is expressible in PA (although ostensibly $\Sigma^0_2$).

For type theories with Prop, there's a bottom type $\bot$ that is initial (i.e., admits a map to every other type), and so consistency would be 'for no term $t$ do we have $\vdash t : \bot$.' This gives a more familiar $\Pi^0_1$ definition of consistency.

The notion of interpretation is a little harder because there doesn't really seem to be a single 'most canonical' notion of 'model' for type theories and some obvious classical notions fail to be sound. (For instance, systems with a lot of polymorphism, such as System F, famously don't have 'naïve' classical set-theoretic models, yet System F is equiconsistent with second-order arithmetic.) Some of this complexity is already present in the model theory of intuitionistic first-order logic, where there are consistent but anti-classical theories.

That said I would guess there's something roughly analogous to Heyting-valued model theory that would be broadly speaking sufficient for defining interpretation.

First of all, I should point out that HoTT with universes (but without propositional resizing or LEM) is in fact a fair bit weaker than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in consistency strength. This is a subtlety that people seem to miss a lot when discussing the consistency strength of type theories.

As Andrej Bauer discussed in a recent answer to another question, there is some sense in which type theory allows for fundamentally greater expressiveness than set theory. In particular, homotopy type theory allows one to reason directly about $\infty$-groupoids without choosing an underlying 'strict' or 'evil' semantic interpretation.
That said, I would argue that a head-to-head comparison between set theory and type theory isn't really all that reasonable since they're built to serve fairly different purposes. Type theory as a field is largely concerned with programming language theory and program extraction from constructive proofs, and set theory as a field is largely concerned with (mostly classical) independence phenomena and reasoning about the infinitary combinatorics of large cardinals. This is reflected in the fact that as formal systems, type theories are largely designed to actually be used in practice (as, for instance, Rocq (née Coq) often is) and set theories are largely designed to have easy to understand syntax and semantics that make metamathematics easier. (Compare for instance the fact that intro graduate set theory courses regularly involve internalization of syntax to the notorious difficulty of formalizing type-theoretic syntax within type theory.)
A rough (but I don't think unreasonable) analogy to programming languages is that type theories are like Haskell and set theories are like x86 assembly code. There are good reasons why both of them exist. Actually writing an end-user program in assembly is a nightmare (although by no means impossible, as demonstrated by the development of the game Rollercoaster Tycoon), but designing a correct chip that implements Haskell on bare metal would also be a nightmare (especially given that (a) Intel famously wasn't even able to get floating point arithmetic right on one of its chips and (b) the developers of Haskell themselves did not implement IO in a satisfactory way in an early version).
This is of course just an analogy, but I do think it has been borne out historically. With the exceptions of Mizar and Metamath, the majority of work in computer formalized mathematics has been done in type-theory-based systems. Even Isabelle/ZF is fundamentally built on a type-theoretic system. This speaks to the practical user-friendliness of actually working in a type theory. But on the other hand, type theory has what I would consider to be an objectively worse track record with inconsistency than set theory does. Martin-Löf's original type theory, which he developed in the 70s, had a type-theoretic version of Russell's paradox, discovered by Girard. This was almost a human lifetime after Russell's paradox had been discovered (which, of course, spurred the original development of type theory by Russell and Whitehead in Principia Mathematica). Similarly, Rocq has included inconsistent principles at some point, and Agda is widely suspected to be inconsistent right now because of issues surrounding 'very dependent types.' In the linked GitHub issue, you can see the following quote:

The term d has type D d, which makes my head hurt if I think too hard about it.

I would argue that these examples (as well as others, such as the uncertain consistency status of certain parts of Voevodsky's original formalization of HoTT and Lean's issues with undecidable type checking and non-transitive definitional equality) point to the fact that type theory's semantics, by virtue of being richer than the semantics of set theory, are materially harder to reason about metamathematically.
I would also argue that some of this inconsistency problem is due to the fact that type theory as a language makes it a little difficult to control consistency strength precisely (and arguably this is a form of 'expressiveness'). For example, several type theories essentially use a large cardinal to prove that $0 \neq 1$. Likewise, there doesn't seem to be a terribly natural way of writing down something like $\mathsf{KP}$ set theory, which has syntactic restrictions on separation and replacement, or $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_1$, which is $\mathsf{PA}$ with a syntactic restriction on induction. This last example is in some sense type theory being a victim of its own elegance. In a first-order formalization of induction, one needs to explicitly state the induction axiom for each formula, which leaves open the possibility of just not including certain instances of induction. In type theory, induction is immediately and automatically extended to all formulas (at least typically).
On the flip side, set theory's simple syntax and semantics have not only lead to fewer notable instances of inconsistency, but have also allowed for some very advanced metamathematics, such as using Shoenfield absoluteness to automatically remove appeals to the axiom of choice from the proofs of certain low complexity statements. This is something which uses Gödel's constructible universe $L$ in an essential way (and as far as I can tell nobody has even really attempted to formalize this in a more 'structural' context like $\mathsf{ETCS}$ or type theory, despite the fact that it is nearly 90 years old). But beyond just the issue of formalizing $L$, even defining the notion of low complexity used here requires the kind of 'evil' set-theoretic coding that type theory is more or less explicitly designed to avoid and uses syntactic metamathematic ideas like prenex normal form which seem difficult to reasonably work with in the kind of rich syntax used in type theory.

+1 Could you give references/books on following statements in your answer to learn more.
"using Shoenfield absoluteness to automatically remove appeals to the axiom of choice from the proofs of certain low complexity statements".
...."in a more 'structural' context like .." what is ETCS.
..." like  set theory, which has syntactic restrictions on separation and replacement, or Σ1, which is  with a syntactic restriction on induction".

@Pradeep I don't know of a great reference for Shoenfield absoluteness. I wrote a couple of MO answers about it (here and here) and I've been thinking about writing an expository article about it for a while now.

ETCS is the elementary theory of the category of sets. I don't know a great reference for it, but the nLab article mentions some. KP is Kripke–Platek set theory; a standard reference here is Admissible Sets and Structures by Barwise. $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_1$ is one of the commonly studied fragments of Peano arithmetic; a standard reference here is Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic by Hájek and Pudlák. Although I should note that those are both pretty heavy books.

@CCC I think that might be what I was thinking of. I'll edit my answer. Also, yes I did write that note. I'm glad it was useful.

@Pradeep you could start with Tom Leinster's informal introduction to ETCS.

Regarding whether type theory is inherently more user-friendly than set theory, see my answer here, where I quote Larry Paulson's opinion that the superior user-friendliness of the type-theoretic systems has more to do with how much effort and funding have gone into them, rather than any inherent inferiority of set theory in this regard.

@JamesEHanson "Rocq has included inconsistent principles at some point": is this an example?

@Pradeep Regarding Shoenfield absoluteness, you might give The Shoenfield Absoluteness Lemma by Barwise and Fisher a try.

@TimothyChow I'm not sure that's an example of what I was referring to. My recollection is that at some point there were inconsistent principles accepted into the kernel, but I don't have a reference at hand.
Regarding user-friendliness, I agree that people often overestimate the extent to which the usability of a proof assistant is the result of fundamental theoretical design decisions as opposed to money spent on UX, and I find it extremely annoying when people criticize set theory on the basis of it not being used in modern proof assistants.

If Microsoft and the US Air Force dumped a bucket of money on UX for Metamath and people spent a bunch of time building a coherent library for it, I think you would likely end up with something roughly as usuable as Lean or Rocq.
That said I do think there's some sense in which one tends to develop something like a type theory when adding in the 'guardrails' one would typically want in a programming environment—Mizar has a soft type system, for instance—but I also think that something like this doesn't need to resemble the current offerings (such as those based on MLTT).

One thing I often wonder about is the extent to which the computational content of constructive type theories is actually relevant in the context of a proof assistant for classical mathematics. People talk about it a lot, but Lean+Mathlib is largely classical and Isabelle/HOL is almost entirely classical and yet they both manage to be quite usable.

It's a bit ironic that all these proof assistants, which are almost surely inconsistent due to programming bugs and having swallowed too many doctoral dissertations research papers published under the pressure of job security, elevate the achievable standards of correctness of proof to a new level never seen before. (I am equally amazed that software is usable at all.)

Isabelle/HOL shows that one needs no constructivity to compute, as there are other ways of combining computation and proof checking. In my opinion, constructivity is desirable for different, inherently mathematical reasons.

I like your analogy between "set theory vs type theory" and "assembly language vs Haskell" (although I usually considered C language as a counterpart of set theory instead.) My impression about set theory (especially from set realizability models appearing on Merlin Carl or Passman's paper about the first-order logic of $\mathsf{CZF}$) is that it can be thought as a theory about a very large computational structure, like Gödel's $L$ or other inner models.

Let me point out that I haven't seen any type-theoretic principle whose strength goes beyond $0^\sharp$. (It can be simply because of my ignorance.) It looks like set theory is currently the only way to express theories stronger than $0^\sharp$ or beyond (aside of some silly examples like HoTT plus projective determinacy.)

Both HoTT and set theory have "canonical interpretations" in each other (I'm glossing over axiomatic strength for now).
The types in HoTT are interpreted as simplical sets (but also see Are simplicial sets the intended model of HoTT?).
The Von Neumann universe in set theory is interpreted by a higher-inductive type $V$ given in Definition 10.5.1 of the HoTT book.
